# Getting text from a button

Tags: android, android-annotations

If I use multiple ids with same @Click event method like

```
@ViewById Button choice1;
@ViewById Button choice2;

    @Click({R.id.choice1,R.id.choice2})
    void choice(){
        //String text = text of the clicked button
    }
```

How will I get the text of the button that is being clicked?

Answer (score 1):

As wrote [on the wiki](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/ClickEvents#click) you can add a `View` parameter in your method signature, like this :

```
@Click({R.id.choice1, R.id.choice2})
void choice(View clickedView) {
    [...]
}
```

Also you don't have to annotate your buttons with `ViewById` in order to use `Click` (unless you really need a reference to these instances, of course)